# Finding $X$ and $\mathcal F$ such that $E(X)<\infty$ and $E(E(X|\mathcal F)^2)=\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, conditional-expectation

> I'm  looking for an example of some random variable $X$ and a sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ such that $E(X)<\infty$ and $E(E(X|\mathcal F)^2)=\infty$, with the requirement that $E(X|\mathcal F) \neq X$ a.s

A natural way would be to look for $X$ and $Y$ such that $E(X)<\infty$, $E(Y)<\infty$, $E(X^2)=E(Y^2)=\infty$ and $E(X|Y)=a Y + b$. I can't come up with such $X$ and $Y$ off the top of my head ...

Comment: Why not take a random variable $X$ with finite mean but infinite second moment (e.g. with pdf $p(x) \sim 1/x^3 1_{\{ x \ge 1 \} }$) together with the $\sigma-$field generated by $X$?

Comment: @Kore-N sorry, I forgot to specify that I want to exclude the trivial examples where $E(X|\mathcal F) = X$ a.s (which will happen if $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal F$).

Comment: We can tweak Kore-N's example. Let $Y, Z$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$ but $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \infty$. Set $X = Y+Z$ and $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(Y)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks ! One last (off-topic) thing, how would you prove that $E(X^2)=\infty$ in your example ?

Comment: One way is to show that $YZ$ is integrable with $\mathbb{E}[YZ] = 0$. Then you can utilize $X^2 = Y^2 + Z^2 + 2YZ$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I've tried this: $$Y\mathbb 1_{|Y|\leq n}Z\mathbb 1_{|Z|\leq n} \to YZ$$ and $$E(Y\mathbb 1_{|Y|\leq n}Z\mathbb 1_{|Z|\leq n})=E( Y\mathbb 1_{|Y|\leq n})E( Z\mathbb 1_{|Z|\leq n})\to E(Y)E(Z)=0$$ The problem is that I can't dominate $Y\mathbb 1_{|Y|\leq n}Z\mathbb 1_{|Z|\leq n}$ by something integrable.

Comment: You may 'bootstrap' your argument in the following way: Consider first the case where $Y$ and $Z$ are non-negative independent r.v.s. (I am not assuming integrability for this case.) Then by the truncation together with the monotone convergence theorem you have $\mathbb{E}[YZ] = \mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[Z]$. For integrable and independent $Y$ and $Z$, you can still count on truncation argument but use the dominate convergence theorem with the dominating function $|YZ|$ (which satisfies $\mathbb{E}[|YZ|] = \mathbb{E}[|Y|]\mathbb{E}[|Z|] < \infty$).

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Y and Z be i.i.d with mean 0 and infinite variance. Let X=Y+Z. Then E(X|Y)=Y  because EZ|Y)=EZ=0. Of course $EX^2$=$\infty$